# How are graphical tabs in Android made?

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

**Screenshots**

[image: KitKat Clock App]
[image: KitKat Peoples App]

**Background**

Graphical tabs started to appear in stock Android application around ICS. However, they are quite different from the traditional tabs ([link](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html)). Moreover, I have found no related tutorials.

**Differences with Traditional Tabs**

1. Graphics instead of text, obviously.
2. No selection indicator at bottom.
3. The color of the contents (graphics) indicates the selection instead.

**Suspicions**

1. Are they just tabs with an icon but no text, combining together with a suitable theme?
2. If yes, how to theme the tabs to achieve such effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that old style tabs were implemented using TabHost and TabWidgets. However, since the introduction of the Action Bar the tabs are implemented as [action bar tabs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs).

You can read about styling the tabs in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Basically you can create your own indicator, as well as choose between icons, text etc.